# In a react native app, when will the redux store get cleared?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to know how and when the redux store gets cleared in a react native app. Does it get cleared when the app close? Does it get cleared when the user clear it from running apps? Or does it clear only when I uninstall the app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends. Redux just creates an object (the store) which is kept alive as long as the JavaScript runs (that means, if you close the app, the store object will be deleted and all information lost). However, if you use a persistence layer on top of redux, say, [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist), your data will be stored in the persistant storage of the application, which gets cleared once you either uninstall the application or, in the Android case, also when you clear the application data.

Answer (score 1):

All the state stored inside the redux store will be cleared when the App is removed from task manager(clear it from running app). When the app is uninstalled all the data related to the app gets cleared such as the local database, file system etc.

The flow goes like this user->trigger action->reducer takes the action, and previous state and update store->updated state stored in the redux store (only one big javascript object)->provider which makes store available to container->data goes to component->user can view data in the component. It's a unidirectional data flow.